# How to match end of last string in file which does not end with punctuation

Tags: bash, awk, grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to search a directory for files which do not end in a period. I'm trying to list the file name with the final ascii character which is not followed by period/ punctuation. I've looked all over and nothing has worked so far. Any help would be so much appreciated!

```
for file in ./dir/*;
do grep -o '[^[:punct:]]$' $file
```

output:

```
filename  f
filename  d
filename  e
```

Where the letters after the filename represent the final character in the file not followed by punctuation.

An empty file should be treated differently to one that doesn't end in punctuation. Empty files are to be ignored. I'm specifically referring to the period/ punctuation inside a file, ignoring filenames.

I am forced to use a mawk version 1.3.4

Comment: are you talking about the period/punctuation not end in filename of file contents?

Comment: Should an empty file be treated the same way as one that doesn't end in punctuation or differently?

Comment: @HansChen I'm referring to the last string within a given file

Comment: @EdMorton They should be treated differently

Comment: OK, [edit] your question to say that and state how they should be treated. Also add sample input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with GNU sed and both the option to treat a file list as separate files and the command `F` to print filename.

```
$ sed -sn '${s/.*\(.\)$/\1/;/[^[:punct:]]/{F;l}}' ./*

./fileone
a$

./filetwo
s$
```

That is assuming the files are all text files. If not, more than one character might get printed. The `l` command is used to avoid problems with a raw binary file output on the console.

#### Description

The first `$` will only match the last line. On that line execute the commands inside the outer `{...}`.

The `s/.*\(.\)$/\1/` will replace the whole line for the last character. On lines that have one or more characters. Empty lines are not changed.

Then, on lines that have no `punct` (`/[^[:punct:]]/`) execute what is inside the second pair of braces `{...}`. That, of course, require that at least one character gets matched, which will reject empty lines.

The code executed on the last line where there is no `punct` is `F` to print the file name and `l` to print the value of the last character of the line (encoded if no ascii).

## Edit

A more restrictive version which avoids binary files could be:

```
sed -sn '${/[[:print:]\t]$/!d;s/.*\(.\)$/\1/;/[^[:punct:]]/{F;l}}' ./*
```

That will not process files where the last character is not `print`able (all numbers, letters (Uppercase and Lowercase), punctuation and space) or a tab.

Comment: Thank you! This works great. Is there a way to exclude blank lines? Or perhaps only look at the last line?

Comment: Description added.  I believe that both needs were covered. The code only looks into the last line, and rejects empty lines. In which way is it not working for you?. @Doodling

Comment: It certainly meets my needs, however with files where there are blank lines before the last line with text in it, it returns the file and a line feed even though the last line of text in the file ends with a dot.

Comment: I hope that you understand that the newline is a result of using the command F, not a reflection of the internal values in the file. It certainly appears for **all** files. If you could confirm that that is a problem you need solving (and please provide an example of the problematic file), I could search for a solution. @Doodling

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes the output of files which end with punctuation is a problem, but I see you already understand that and I'm not doing a great job at explaining. I've tried to recreate the problem with test files and your suggestion works perfectly without incident so there is something in the files I'm trying to manipulate which is causing the issue. I will investigate.

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you're trying to do, using GNU awk for `ENDFILE`:

```
awk 'ENDFILE {
    if ( FNR ) {
        c = substr($0,length(),1)
        if ( c !~ /[[:punct:]]/ ) {
            print FILENAME, c
        }
    }
}' dir/*
```

or with any POSIX awk:

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 { prt(); fname=FILENAME }
    { lastRec = $0 }
    END { prt() }
    function prt(    c) {
        c = substr(lastRec,length(),1)
        if ( c !~ /[[:punct:]]/ ) {
            print fname, c
        }
    }
' dir/*
```

or if your awk is non-POSIX (as mawk 1 which you currently have may well be) then to make it work with any awk replace `[[:punct:]]` with a bracket expression containing the hard-coded list of punctuation characters (characters that are not letters, digits, control characters, or space characters), e.g. `[-.,!=+]` etc., or change the comparison from `!~` to `~` and change `[[:punct:]]` to the list of characters that are not punctuation characters (characters that are not letters, digits, control characters, or space characters), e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9 \t]` etc.

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce a result

Comment: @Doodling then you're doing something other than what I show in my script. Maybe you aren't using GNU awk or are using a very old version before ENDFILE existed?

Comment: I just checked awk version it's old, version 1.3.4

Comment: That's not even gawk, it's an old minimal featured version of mawk. Get gawk. If that's impossible update your question to state  you're stuck with mawk 1 (mawk 2 has many gawk features).

Comment: I added a solution that'll work in any awk.

Comment: Both scripts process a last empty line, Technically: an empty line has no ASCII character to print (as requested).

Comment: The second script fails to print the last character in many cases. Try a file which is simply `echo abcd >file77`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to find file contents ending without punctuation:

`for f in ./* ; do tail -n 1 "$f" | grep -qv '[^[:punct:]]$' || echo "$f" ; done`

In case you need to find filenames ending without punctuation:

`find . | grep -v '[[:punct:]]$'`

Comment: Is there a way to include the last character before the missing dot? for example 

filename: h